# Rails linking to another controller in different view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I this view is currently in the views/projects/show.html.erb file however I want it to use the website controller for deleting this file:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @website, :controller => 'website', :action => 'delete', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you  want to delete this asset?"}%>
```

It returns the error 'Could not find action destroy in the ProjectsController'. Also i don't have @website defined in the projects controller so should I be using something else? Or am I still able to access it because it is defined in the websites controller.

```
#controllers/websites_controller.rb
    class WebsitesController < ApplicationController

    def new

        @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
        @website = @project.assets.build(:type => 'Website', :project_id => Project.find(params[:project_id]), :asset_number => @project.assets.size + 1)

        end


    def create
        @website = current_user.assets.build(website_params)
        @website.update_attributes(:project_id => @project)

    if @website.save
      flash[:notice] = "Asset successfully added."
      redirect_to(:controller => 'projects', :action => 'show', :id => @website.project_id)
    else
      render(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

   def delete
    @website = Asset.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    asset = Asset.find(params[:id]).destroy
     flash[:notice] = "The asset '#{asset.title}' has been destroyed Successfully."
    redirect_to(:controller => 'projects', :action => 'index')
  end

  private

  def website_params
    params.require(:website).permit(:id, :project_id, :asset_number, :title, :type, :url, :page_rank, :rev_company ,:social_pages)
  end



end
```

Comment: if you are using this link on the show page for projects then @website will not be available unless it is defined in the projects controller

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this link on the show page for projects then @website will not be available unless it is defined in the projects controller.

That said, if there is some relationship between the project and the website, you could use that as opposed to defining @website in your projects controller.

Also, as far as your link_to is concerned, I do not believe that you can specify controller and action in the link_to like that.  Instead, you should use the path to @website.  Which should make your link_to look something more like this:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", website_path(@website), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you  want to delete this asset?" %>
```

However, the model that your websites_controller appears to handle is actually an Asset.  Without seeing your routes it is hard to guess how you have set them up, but assuming that you do something like

```
map.resources :assets, :controller => 'websites'
```

in your routes.  Then in your link_to instead of using website_path(@website) you would likely use asset_path(@website).

Generally speaking, it is rarely a good idea to defy rails convention by naming things inconsistently from your model in ruby.  If your Asset model uses single table inheritance or you are implying something like single table inheritance and are using controllers to separate responsibilities, then this may perhaps be an exception, but you will still need to be careful to ensure you are mapping to the correct place in your routes.

You may want to read up on the [rails guide for routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), as it is a very good resource and explains pretty well how destroy gets mapped, which in turn explains why the link_to for it looks the way that it does.

Answer (score 0):

`@website` available in the show action is the the one defined in the projects controller because it is he one rendering the current html page.
Therefore the one you wish to delete is not available at the moment.